# How to configure resolution in carousel bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I was searching any option but don't found.how to configure the resolution of carousel.I will give a example:
Real Image:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EORbj.jpg

In carousel:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sUxmR.jpg

This configuration have in bootstrap?Or is made in CSS